# Heat not warming house

Tags: heating

Here's the back story. Last night, house was 70 degrees. Knowing that over night it would get chilly, I put the heat on 68 degrees.

This morning I woke up and the heat was still of course set to 68 degrees, but the house was 64 degrees! I also noticed that the thermostat said **AUX HEAT ON**.

Any thoughts on why this would be the case? This is a heat pump, by the way.

1. Why would there be a 4 degree difference with the heat running?
2. Why would the auxiliary heat be on?

I understand the aux heat kicks on when there isn't enough heat outside, but it didn't get much below 40 degrees last night, possibly even a low of 45 degrees.

Comment: What make and model is your HVAC system?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Williams? Does that sound about right? Even now, it's noon here and the heat is still running. House is only at 66 degrees (it's 54 degrees outside at the moment). This just doesn't seem right.

Comment: @ThomasStringer filter clean? Outside condenser clean?  If so, it's probably best that you call a serviceman.

Comment: Air source heat pump systems can suffer from freezing in the outside unit. This is particularly likely when temperatures are just above freezing and it's wet.

Comment: Wow I turned the heat off (the house is just not warming up, staying at 66 degrees). And now the fan itself won't turn off. Heat is off, and fan is set to "auto". Fan is staying on. Awfully peculiar to have two separate issues like this..?

Comment: @ThomasStringer -- a model number would be quite helpful here, or better yet, wiring diagrams for your system

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel dumb question, but where do I find the model number? And the wiring diagram?

Comment: @ThomasStringer -- should both be on labels on the indoor unit